# OpenCV not working when ran with sudo

Tags: opencv, sudo

I have an application that uses OpenCV, and now want it to also access GPIO pins, so it needs to run as sudo. So, I tried to run it using "sudo python3 myapp.py"

When I do I get the following error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "myapp.py", line 318, in admin_screen_cam1
    cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'VideoCapture'
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "myapp.py", line 1348, in <module>
    home_screen()
  File "myapp.py", line 1250, in home_screen
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

I have not added the GPIO code, and if I simply run "python3 myapp.py" the application runs without issue.

Any help defining why I could be getting this error when attempting to run with sudo would be appreciated. It is the last thing I need to finish (of course).

Answer (score 0):

And nevermind.

This was resolved with a simple:
sudo apt install python3-opencv

I thought I had tried that, but I guess not. Grr...